# Python Socket Server receives gibberish text files, after client sends an text file

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp, utf-8

I created a client (C Language to send file) and server (Python Language to receive) to test sending and receiving .txt file.
However, when I did try to send and receive it with the server, the received file contains the original text+gibberish text.
Below is the server code (receive file) in Python:

```
import socket

#Set up socket
IP_SERVER = "127.0.0.1"
HEADER = 1024
PORT = 15000
ADDR = (IP_SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(ADDR)
server_socket.listen()


#Set up file 
file =open("dari_client.txt","wb")
connected = True
while connected :
    conn,addr = server_socket.accept()
    terima = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    print("Client connected \n")
    while terima:
        file.write(terima)
        terima = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    file.close()
    connected = False

conn.close()
```

Below is my Client code in C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>

void kirim_file(int socket,FILE *fl)
{
    int n;
    char data[1024];
    while (fgets(data,1024,fl) != NULL){
        send(socket,data,sizeof(data),0);
    }
    bzero(data,1024);
}

int main(){
    int network_socket,cli;
    FILE *fl;
    char nama_file[20] = "pesan.txt";
    network_socket = socket(AF_INET ,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // socket server address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address,client_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(15000);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    fl = fopen(nama_file,"r");
    kirim_file(network_socket,fl);

    close(network_socket);
}
```

Gibberish can be seen in this picture:
[Gibberish received file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFO8H.png)

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try without the call to `.decode(FORMAT)`. BTW, what python version are you using that would allow you to write a string (instead of a bytes object are returned by .recv) to a file opened with mode='wb'?

Comment: What format is the original textfile? I doubt it is ascii and as the decode does not respect network byte order for multibyte text it gets it all wrong.

Comment: Sorry, i've just seen that the c code contains an error: `send(socket,data,sizeof(data),0);` sends always 1024 bytes but you want to send one line at a time, only. You want `strlen(data)` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel already tried without .decode(format) and I got an "utf8' codec can't decode byte......." error

Comment: hi @pqans the textfile is in UTF-8 when I save it, will try to use strlen(data), thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is at least in part because you are sending the entire array `data` rather than just the content that you read from the file. From the man page for `string.h`:

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)`
>
> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the  buffer  pointed  to  by  s.
> Reading  stops  after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte
> ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So each time you read the file you are sending both the read data, and all the garbage data stored in the rest of the buffer `data`. Probably the simplest way is to check for the amount of data read, rather than sending all of `data` each time:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>

void kirim_file(int socket,FILE *fl)
{
    int n;
    char data[1024];

    while (fgets(data, 1024, fl) != NULL){
        int length = strnlen(data, 1024);

        send(socket, data, length, 0);
    }

    bzero(data,1024);
}
```

Comment: hi, will try to do this, I will update you about the result, thanks!